# Sort CSV file and display in HTML table with PHP

Tags: php, html, csv, html-table

I have a CSV file that has (dummy) data like this:

```
Mike Judge, Office Space, Comedy
Larry Wachowski, Matrix Zero, Action
Sofia Coppola, Lost In Translation, Drama
Ron Howard, A Beautiful Mind, Drama
Joe Biden, Your Big Hat, Sports
Barack Obama, The Stubborn Goat, Drama
Steve Smith, 2 Beautiful Ants, Suspense
Jared Hess, Napoleon Dynamite, Comedy
Jack Daniels, Field of Dreams, Drama
```

I need the 1st field sorted alphabetically by last name. That works.

Then I need to show the array in an HTML table and be able to set the number of columns to perhaps 5. I need each cell to hold one line from the CSV file, then move left to right filling the table.

Everything I've tried gets me almost there, but the table does not display properly - it has missing td tag or no `&nbsp;` in the last td.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 $file = fopen("dummy-list.csv", "r") or die('cannot open file');

// sort
$surnames = array();
$rows = array();
//build array of surnames, and array of rows
while (false != ( $row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ',') )) {
    //extract surname from the first column
    //this should match the last word before the comma, if there is a comma
    preg_match('~([^\s]+)(?:,.*)?$~', $row[0], $m);
    $surnames[] = $m[1];
    $rows[] = $row;
}
//fclose($file);
//sort array of rows by surname using our array of surnames
array_multisort($surnames, $rows);
//print_r($rows);


// set # of table columns
$numCols = 4;
$i=0;


echo '<table border="1" align="center"><tr>' . "\n";
foreach( $rows as $rows2 )
{

if ($i % $numCols == 0 && $i != 0) 
    echo "</tr>\n<tr>"; // every time but the first

    echo '<td>';

    foreach( $rows2 as $key )
    {
            echo $key . '<br />';
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</td>\n";
}


while ($i++ % $numCols != 0) 
echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>' . "\n"; // fill in empty cells


// end table
echo '</tr></table>' . "\n\n\n";
```

Comment: I achieve this by converting the CSV to JSON and using DataTables for this

Comment: This is what we used tables for in 1998.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: GolezTrol - your comment is not helpful unless you are going to recommend what you use now in 2016...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to modify your logic slightly. Currently, your script doesn't track which column your in, so it has no way of knowing how many cells to pad.

The biggest logical problem is:

```
while ($i++ % $numCols != 0) 
echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>' . "\n"; // fill in empty cells
```

All that is doing is checking that the number of columns is devisable by $i.  so, after $i gets to 3, it stops. (in this case 4/3 != 0)

The following works:

```
$file = fopen("dummy-list.csv", "r") or die('cannot open file');

// sort
$surnames = array();
$rows = array();
//build array of surnames, and array of rows
while (false != ( $row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ',') )) {
   //extract surname from the first column
   //this should match the last word before the comma, if there is a comma
   preg_match('~([^\s]+)(?:,.*)?$~', $row[0], $m);
   $surnames[] = $m[1];
   $rows[] = $row;
}
//fclose($file);
//sort array of rows by surname using our array of surnames
array_multisort($surnames, $rows);
//print_r($rows);


// set # of table columns
$numCols = 4;
$i=0;
$cellpos = 0; //count columns

echo '<table border="1" align="center"><tr>' . "\n";
//use the amount of rows as a divisor
for($c=0; $c<Count($rows); $c++ )
{

    if ($i % $numCols == 0 && $i != 0){
       echo "</tr>\n<tr>"; // every time but the first
       $cellpos=0;  //reset our column position
    }

    echo '<td>';
    //then, call each csv row explicitly
    foreach( $rows[$c] as $key )
    {
        echo $key . '<br />';
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</td>\n";
    $cellpos++;  //track our column position
}

while ($cellpos++ < $numCols)
echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>' . "\n"; // fill in empty cells


// end table
echo '</tr></table>' . "\n\n\n";
```

I added $cellpos variable to count the td in each row, as your populating. It gets reset every time you start a new row. if you track that var through the script you will see my changes.

Additionally, if you want to do something more specific with those keys, you can call them directly instead of just looping over the row. Just change the code between `<td>` tags.

```
echo '<td>';

//then, call each csv celldata explicitly

    echo '<a href="' . $rows[$c][0]. '"><img src="'. $rows[$c][1] . '" /><br />' .$rows[$c][2] . '</a>';
    $i++;

echo "</td>\n";
```

Comment: dval - if I change my csv to: Mike Judge, artists/judge.php, images/bikini.jpg
Larry Wachowski, artists/wachowski.php, images/wachowski.jpg
Sofia Coppola, artists/coppola.php, images/coppola.jpg

Comment: this code does not work: //echo $key . '<br />';
        
      
        echo "<a href=" . $rows[$c][1]. "><img src=". $rows[$c][2] . " /><br />";
  echo $rows[$c][0] . "</a>";

Comment: @user888864 you need to format that line correctly, your using double quotes to define a string, but the string also has double quotes. you need to either use single quotes around your HTML, or escape all the double quotes in the string.  Here is the string correctly formatted:  `echo '<a href="' . $rows[$c][0]. '"><img src="'. $rows[$c][1] . '" /><br />' .$rows[$c][2] . '</a>';`  Additionally, you need to comment out the foreach loop, because instead of looping through the row, you are now explicitly declaring the keys `$rows[$c][0]` , etc... I'll update my answer to reflect this

Comment: and by 'explicitly declaring the keys' I meant 'explicitly calling'.

Comment: When I comment out the foreach loop, I get extra td cells......sorry to be a pain.....but thank you so much for your help. Is there a site where we can demo this code so that it's easier for me to see it in full? ideone.com or codepen.com?

Comment: @user888864 I had to make a change to how the csv gets read, because you can't actually read external files from ideone. (Great site, thank you!) but, everything else is as I copied it from my text editor. http://ideone.com/1flLmg  When you change the column count, you get the appropriate cell counts. hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Stay with your code:

Change this:

```
while ($i++ % $numCols != 0) 
echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>' . "\n"; // fill in empty cells
```

For it:

```
$mod = $numCols-count($rows)%$numCols;

for($i=0;($i < ($mod) && $mod != $numCols);$i++)
    echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>' . "\n";
```

And solve your problems!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MOD operator to check if you are at the end of a column and then end the row, and start a new one:

```
$cols = 4;
$count = count($rows);

$table_html ="<tr>";
for($i=0; $i < $count; ++$i){
    $table_html.= '<td>' . implode("<br>", $rows[$i]) . '</td>';
    if($i != 0 && ($i % $cols == 0)){
        $table_html.="</tr>";
    }
}
$table_html.="</tr>";
echo $table_html;
```